# Altering a View to have an Attribute Value as a new Attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to add an attribute Value as a new attribute.

[image]

I want to add the Value column as a new attribute in my view. How can I do this in SQL Server 2008? We are using Dynamics 2011, and this is for use on our partner portal site. I'm not good with SQL hence why I'm asking.

The SQL query to get the table of Attribtues and AttributeValue is:

```
SELECT     sm.Value, sm.AttributeValue
FROM         dbo.pt_mirror_stringmap AS sm INNER JOIN
                      dbo.pt_mirror_entitylogicalview AS pme ON 
pme.ObjectTypeCode = sm.ObjectTypeCode
WHERE     (sm.AttributeName = 'forecastrole')
```

Comment: you use `INSERT` statement to insert a row to the table. Example https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: I don't understand the question, maybe if you try to reformulate it you can help yourself and us to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics CRM already comes with out of the box views which show the human readable values of option sets. These views are called [Filtered Views](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531182.aspx), and also honor the security model in CRM.

I would advise you to simply use the filtered view for your entity. If you really need to create your own view, you can always find inspiration in how the default views are made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plain table query, you will get integer value (code) directly from your entity and have to inner join with `StringMapBase` table to get label (name). [Read more](https://technicalreflections.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/crm-2011-stringmap-table/)

```
select AttributeName, AttributeValue, Value from StringMapBase
where LangId = 1033 and AttributeName = 'TheNameOfTheAttribute'
```

Like Henrik said, `FilteredViews` are your best bet. For some reason if you have your own views - then pull the `AttributeValue` like the above query in your view definition.

> All drop-down lists (option sets) have two associated fields for every string in the list. For each string, there is a value (code) field and a label (name) field, such as, leadsource and leadsourcename. For example, the filtered view for Leads returns two fields related to the LeadSource attribute of type Picklist: LeadSource = 1 and LeadSourceName =“Advertisement”. Reports display the label field and use the value field for numeric comparisons.

Reference: [Use SQL and filtered views to retrieve data for reports](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531161.aspx#Naming%20conventions%20in%20the%20Microsoft%20Dynamics%20365%20database)

Comment: I should add that we are using Dynamics 2011

Comment: @scoobs can you add the current code/query you are using & how do you want to modify? the concept in answer does not change wrt crm version

Comment: I need the label value of an option set and I need to insert that value into my view so I can access it from our portal site...

Comment: @scoobs your dbo.pt_mirror_entitylogicalview should have AttributeValue stored in each record. To get respective Value only you have to join stringmap.

Comment: I figured this issue out by using a stored procedure to retrieve the Value

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to use function in sql server that would return the values I needed:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[getAttributeValue]
(
    @attributename nvarchar(100), @attributevalue int 
)
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @value nvarchar(4000)

select @value = value
from pt_mirror_stringmap
where attributename = @attributename
    and attributevalue = @attributevalue

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @value
END
```